# Runtime error on my code for CodeChef: Fit To Play (PLAYFIT)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I submitted code for [this CodeChef problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PLAYFIT):

> Rayne Wooney has been one of the top players for his football club for
> the last few years. But unfortunately, he got injured during a game a
> few months back and has been out of play ever since.
>
> He's got proper treatment and is eager to go out and play for his team
> again. Before doing that, he has to prove to his fitness to the coach
> and manager of the team. Rayne has been playing practice matches for
> the past few days. He's played N practice matches in all.
>
> He wants to convince the coach and the manager that he's improved over
> time and that his injury no longer affects his game. To increase his
> chances of getting back into the team, he's decided to show them stats
> of any 2 of his practice games. The coach and manager will look into
> the goals scored in both the games and see how much he's improved. If
> the number of goals scored in the 2<sup>nd</sup> game(the game which took place
> later) is greater than that in 1st, then he has a chance of getting
> in. Tell Rayne what is the maximum improvement in terms of goal
> difference that he can show to maximize his chances of getting into
> the team. If he hasn't improved over time, he's not fit to play.
> Scoring equal number of goals in 2 matches will not be considered an
> improvement. Also, he will be declared unfit if he doesn't have enough
> matches to show an improvement.
>
> #### Input:
>
> The first line of the input contains a single integer *T*, the number of test cases. Each test case begins with a single integer
> *N*, the number of practice matches Rayne has played.
>
> The next line contains *N* integers. The *i* <sup>th</sup> integer,
> *g*<sub>i</sub>, on this line represents the number of goals Rayne scored in his *i* <sup>th</sup> practice match. The matches are given
> in chronological order i.e. *j > i* means match number *j* took place
> after match number *i*.
>
> #### Output:
>
> For each test case output a single line containing the maximum goal difference that Rayne can show to his coach and manager.
> If he's not fit yet, print "UNFIT".
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - 1 ≤ *T* ≤ 10
> - 1 ≤ *N* ≤ 100000
> - 0 ≤ *g*<sub>i</sub> ≤ 1000000 (Well, Rayne's a legend! You can expect him to score so many goals!)

My code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    num = int(input())
    goals = list(map(int,input().split()))
    list1 = []
    for i in range(num-1):
        diff = goals[i+1]-goals[i]
        list1.append(diff)
    if max(list1)>0:
        print(max(list1))
    else:
        print('UNFIT')
```

Codechef's giving me a Runtime Error. Why is that?

Comment: What are the constraints for the problem? Can it be of size 1 as well?

Answer (score 0):

The constraints allow *N* to be just 1. In that case your `list1` is empty, and `max([])` will produce the following error:

> ValueError: `max()` arg is an empty sequence

The challenge mentions what you should return in such a case:

> Also, he will be declared unfit if he doesn't have enough matches to show an improvement.

To solve this issue, change this line:

```
if max(list1)>0:
```

to:

```
if list1 and max(list1)>0:
```

#### Other remarks

- Use meaningful variable names. `list1` tells us what the data type is, but not what it is for.
- Building `list1` gives some overhead and will use *O(N)* extra space. Try to do it without creating a list.